# What is the meaning of a quote by Walt Whitman as follows

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am trying to make sense of the following which I assume is a reference to the conflict with the American Indians. Specifically, what do the pronouns "they" and "it" respectively refer to in the following quotation?

> What is any Nation, after all — and what is a human being; — but a struggle between conflicting, paradoxical, opposing elements — and **they** themselves and their most violent contests, important parts of that One Identity, and of **its** development?

Walt Whitman 1875 copied from a wall in a Texas museum

Comment: What do you think it is trying to say?

Comment: I have no idea...that is why I copied it from a wall in a museum in Texas and initiate the question here. I assume that It was about the conflict with Indians. Specifically whom/what  do "they“, "its" refer to here respectively?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Whom or what do "they“, "its" refer to here respectively?

Comment: I edited your post, since I'd like to know the answer too and it seems people are voting to close on the basis that it's unclear. If you don't like the edits let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt about pronoun elements, a quick test is to refer to the nearest preceding noun or noun phrase that could agree with it in number or function. By that test, use this:

> What is any Nation, after all — and what is a human being; — but a struggle between conflicting, paradoxical, opposing **elements** — and **they** themselves and their most violent contests, important parts of that **One Identity**, and of **its** development?

By this test, "they" refers to *elements* and "its" refers to *that one Identity*. So, plug them in and see whether they make sense:

> What is any Nation, after all — and what is a human being; — but a struggle between conflicting, paradoxical, opposing **elements** — and **(these) elements** themselves and their most violent contests, important parts of that **One Identity**, and of **that One Identity's** development?

In this case, both readings work. Within a nation or a person, the elements contest, and this contest is a part of Whitman's "One Identity."

If one of the pronoun/noun substitutions didn't work, you would need to go further back to try to find a noun or noun phrase that fits better. Sometimes no perfectly fitting word or phrase will work. This means that the pronoun refers to something *ambiguous* (it could refer to two or more NPs), *remote* (it's in another sentence), or *vague* (it's unclear if it refers to anything in-text). (ThoughtCo has more on "[Faulty Pronoun Reference](https://www.thoughtco.com/faulty-pronoun-reference-4103463).")

Comment: @Tuffy. I think this should be under the original post.

Comment: @SConroy Yes it should.  Sorry, but I have never worked out how to do that once a discussion has moved on a bit.

Comment: This sounds right. I also think a modern reader could at least mentally delete the first 'and' and insert a 'being' between 'contests' and 'important'.

Comment: Many thanks go to S Conroy, Tuffy and TaliesinMerlin for your kind assistance and detailed explanation.
Now I think that the original paragraph may be understood as follows (please correct me if I am wrong):
What is any Nation or a human being? It is just a struggle between elements,  and these elements and their contests make up parts of the One Identity and its development.

Comment: I don't know why they believe that this question is off-topic. The original sentence is a bit too conceptual, abstract and philosophical to understand to me.  I asked a few native English-speaking friends but they didn't give me some clues in terms of ELU
Perhaps I should have run the sentence online first to get to know the context, then come down to the specific question of the reference of "they" and "its" and check my grammar book.